# About conversion to dB

Tags: matlab

So I have been dealing with the hydrophone data and coding in matlab. I have couple of questions as follows -
1. I read all the .wav files in matlab and trying to compute the Power spectral density using pwelch in matlab which im able to do with ease. My question is conversion to dB. The hydrophone output is in Voltage/Micropascal. So in order to obtain the Power spectral density values in dB do I simply do 120 + 10*log10(Power)? This is what i did and the Power in brackets here is the output of using pwelch and the values are like 10 power of -6..

2. How do I get sound pressure levels(SPL (dB re 1 micropascal) from the power spectral density values in dB?
3. How do I chose specific frequency band of interest, say I want to look at power spectral density in the frequency 10 to 12kHz then how do i go about?

Many thanks .

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network - [Signal Processing Stack Exchange](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: All different branches use their own definition of decibel. It has all to do with the reference. A tip is to consult your colleagues. It is unlikely that you will find someone here who can answer. If you are lucky you might get an answer on dsp stack exchange. Regarding (3), there is far too little information there. I do not even understand enough to ask you to clarify anything.